# Form vs Fetch API not rendering the redirect page js

Tags: javascript

I have a button that on click makes a fetch POST call to /portal.

```
portalButton.click(function () {
    console.log(customerID);
    fetch("/portal", {
      method: "POST", redirect: 'follow', mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify({ customer: customerID }),
    })
});
```

I have a simple Express /portal endpoint that redirects to another URL, say google.com,

```
app.post("/portal", async (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://google.com");
});
```

Clicking the button I get an error like below and the page does not redirect.

`Access to fetch at 'https://google.com/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:4242/portal') from origin 'http://localhost:4242' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

But if I have the button in a form, I get no cors error and the page is successfully redirected.

```
<form name="myForm" action="/portal" method="post">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Question:

1. What is the difference between form post and fetch post in this context? (Yes, I did read the fetch API documentation)
2. Why do I get the CORS error only when I do fetch call and not when I do the form call - aren't they both requesting data (the redirect) from a different resource?

Thank you!

Comment: a redirect from an ajax doesn't redirect the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between form post and fetch post in this context?

Submitting the form causing the browser to navigate to the new URL.

`fetch` returns the data to be handled by JavaScript without causing the browser to navigate at all (although you don't do anything with the return value of `fetch`).

> Why do I get the CORS error only when I do fetch call and not when I do the form call - aren't they both requesting data (the redirect) from a different resource?

CORS is designed to protect data that should be private between The User and Website A being accessed by JavaScript running on Website B.

That couldn't happen if JavaScript wasn't involved in the first place.